# How to use generic type for JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to use a generic type for JpaRepository. I do this because I want my core code isolate from the Spring Data JPA and Spring Boot, and use my handlers to access data.
However, I got this error:

```
Field repository in com.ecobike.database.handler.CRUD required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - customerRepository: defined in com.ecobike.database.repository.CustomerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration
    - dockRepository: defined in com.ecobike.database.repository.DockRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration
    - repositoryProxy: defined in com.ecobike.database.repository.RepositoryProxy defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Code:
CustomerRepository.java

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends RepositoryProxy<Customer> {
}
```

DockRepository.java

```java
public interface DockRepository extends RepositoryProxy<Dock> {
}
```

RepositoryProxy.java

```java
public interface RepositoryProxy<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

CRUD.java

```java
@Component
public class CRUD<T> {
    @Autowired
    private JpaRepository<T, Long> repository;

    public void create(T object) {
    }

    public List<T> getAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public T get(String id) {
        return null;
    }

    public void update(T object) {
    }

    public void delete(T object) {
    }
}
```

CustomerDBHandler.java

```java
public class CustomerDBHandler extends CRUD<Customer> {
    @Getter
    private static final CustomerDBHandler instance = new CustomerDBHandler();
}
```

DockDBHandler.java

```java
public class DockDBHandler extends CRUD<Dock> {
    @Getter
    private static final DockDBHandler instance = new DockDBHandler();
}
```

Comment: You create three repositories, plus a single component `CRUD`. How do you expect Spring to know which repository to inject into `CRUD`?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for me to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

For CRUD class, JpaRepository is not needed to be autowired because it does not know which repository to refer yet. Instead, I would pass the class and SimpleJpaRepository variables to build generic JpaRepository as below:

```
public abstract class CRUD<T> {
    private JpaRepository<T, Long> repository;
    private Class<T> clazz;
    public void setClazz(Class<T> clazzToSet, SimpleJpaRepository<T, Long> repository) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    //...
}
```

Then, we can have our repository classes with respect to the entities.

```
@Repository
class FooDao extends CRUD {
    public FooDao(EntityManager entityManager) {
        SimpleJpaRepository<Foo, Serializable> repository = new SimpleJpaRepository<Foo, Serializable>(Foo.class, entityManager);
        setClazz(Foo.class, repository);
    }
}

@Repository
class BarDao extends CRUD {
    public BarDao(EntityManager entityManager) {
        SimpleJpaRepository<Bar, Serializable> repository = new SimpleJpaRepository<Bar, Serializable>(Bar.class, entityManager);
        setClazz(Bar.class, repository);
    }
}
```

Finally, we can use our custom codes inside CRUD class easily.

```
@Autowired FooDao fooDao;
@Autowired BarDao barDao;
fooDao.getAll()
barDao.getAll()
```